# How to force an input html element to show only the last inputted character

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to create an input:

```
<input type='text' id='in'></input>
```

When the user types a character the input will hold that character.
But when the user types a different character, the input will hold the new character. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follows an example:

```html
<input type='text' id='in' onkeydown="this.value = ''"></input>
```